# Get python object using its data

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I have written this class to create a tree in python:

```
class Tree: 
    def init(self, name, cell=""):
        self.name = name
        self.cell = cell
        self.children = []
        self.parent = None

    def add_child(self, child):
        child.parent = self
        self.children.append(child)
```

The data input available requires me to build this tree from the middle in random steps so that there is no way to have the root beforehand. The nodes may not even connect to other nodes at first.

Is there a way to make the last line work? To get the object using its name?

```
node = Tree("A", cell = "A_cell")
node.add_child(Tree("B", cell = "B_cell"))
node.add_child(Tree("C", cell = "C_cell"))
node.add_child(Tree("D", cell = "D_cell"))
print(Tree("B").cell)
```

Expected response is "B_cell" but I get an empty string.

Comment: you need to write code that does that. You could, for example, keep a dictionary that maps the name to the node.

Comment: You can check how this is implemented in other tree libraries. If you need instant access to the direct children of a certain node, you can store the children in a dictionary. This is implemented (by me) in [littletree](https://github.com/lverweijen/littletree). If you need access to any node (even several layers deep) in the tree by name, you can take a look at [treelib](https://github.com/caesar0301/treelib) instead, which stores all nodes in a registry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing `print(Tree("B").cell)` creates a new `Tree` instance with the default value for the `cell` attribute, an empty string. That object is different from the one created in `node.add_child(Tree("B", cell = "B_cell"))`.

If you want to use that syntax (`print(Tree("B").cell)`), you would have to avoid generating more than one instance of the class with the same "name" attribute. To achieve this, one option would be to use a metaclass and override the `__call__` method, for example:

```
import weakref


class MetaTree(type):
    instances = weakref.WeakValueDictionary()
    def __call__(cls, name, cell=""):
        if not (instance := cls.instances.get(name)):
            instance = cls.__new__(cls)
            instance.__init__(name, cell)
            cls.instances[name] = instance
        return instance

class Tree(metaclass=MetaTree):
    def __init__(self, name, cell=""):
        self.name = name
        self.cell = cell
        self.children = []
        self.parent = None

    def add_child(self, child):
        child.parent = self
        self.children.append(child)
        
    
node = Tree("A", cell = "A_cell")
node.add_child(Tree("B", cell = "B_cell"))
node.add_child(Tree("C", cell = "C_cell"))
node.add_child(Tree("D", cell = "D_cell"))
print(Tree("B").cell)
```

Note that nothing prevents someone from reassigning another value to the `name` attribute of one or more instances once created (`node.name = "X"`), which may have unexpected results. In theory the `name` attribute should be immutable once the instance is created.

Making an instance attribute immutable (without ways to circumvent it) in Python is... complicated. What is recommended is to avoid that it is modified by mistake, for example using a property without setter:

```
class Tree(metaclass=MetaTree):
    def __init__(self, name, cell=""):
        self._name = name
        self.cell = cell
        self.children = []
        self.parent = None
    
    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name

    def add_child(self, child):
        child.parent = self
        self.children.append(child)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should implement some "registry" - a place where each object of your type can be found. The most convenient is a dictionary, indexed by name. Store it in a place common to all objects - for example, in your `Tree` class.

```
class Tree: 
    registry = {}
```

When creating each object, you should add it to the registry.

```
class Tree:
    def __init__(self, name, cell=""):
        Tree.registry[name] = self
```

To retrieve an existing object from the registry, define a class method. Using a constructor for this could be possible (I don't know how) but I think it doesn't make sense, because constructors should create new objects and not find existing ones.

```
class Tree:
    @classmethod    
    def find_object_by_name(cls, name):
        return cls.registry[name]
```

Note the `@classmethod` decorator and the name `cls` ("class") of first argument - this method is a property of the class, not of each object.

Full code:

```
class Tree:
    registry = {}

    def __init__(self, name, cell=""):
        self.name = name
        self.cell = cell
        self.children = []
        self.parent = None
        type(self).registry[name] = self

    def add_child(self, child):
        child.parent = self
        self.children.append(child)

    @classmethod    
    def find_object_by_name(cls, name):
        return cls.registry[name]

node = Tree("A", cell = "A_cell")
node.add_child(Tree("B", cell = "B_cell"))
node.add_child(Tree("C", cell = "C_cell"))
node.add_child(Tree("D", cell = "D_cell"))
print(Tree.find_object_by_name("B").cell)
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't understand how you want your list to be formed. But from your expected output, I guess that this is what you want:

```
class Tree: 
    def __init__(self, name, children = []):
        self.name = name
        self.children =children
    
    def add_child(self, other):
        self.children.append([self.name, other])
        return self.children
    
    def cell(self):
        for x in self.children:
            if x[0]==self.name:
                return x[1]
        
    
Tree("A").add_child('A_cell')
Tree('B').add_child('B_cell')
Tree('C').add_child('C_cell')
Tree('D').add_child('D_cell')
r = Tree('B').cell()
print(r) # Output : 'B_cell'
```

To show you what kind of list it will create, I'm printing the output of Tree('D').add_child('D cell') here:

```
print(Tree('D').add_child('D cell'))

# output: [['A', 'A_cell'], ['B', 'B_cell'], ['C', 'C cell'], ['D', 'D_cell']]
```

That is after calling the class every time continuously, another child-list is added without removing the previous child-list from the parent list.

Instead if the entire class is given as the argument of the class' function, it will create an endless loop.

Answer (score -1):

The line `Tree("B").cell` returns an empty line because you are creating a new Tree instance with `name` value`"B"` and `cell` value `""`, because this is the default cell value you provide in the `Tree` constructor. When you access the `cell` property of that new Tree, you just get back the empty string it was created with.

To get the value you want, you will likely need to implement some sort of Tree searching algorithm that recurses through the tree given a starting/root node, and finds the node you are looking for within its child nodes. You can then print the `cell` value of the returned node, if it exists. An inefficient but basic recursive method would look like:

```
def find_node(tree, name):
    if tree.name == name:
        return tree

    for child in tree.children:
        found_node = find_node(child, name)
        if found_node:
            return found_node

    return None
```

If you add this method to the `Tree` class, you can then call `node.find_node("B")` to get the node you are looking for. Be careful to check that a node has been returned before you access any attributes, in case no node is found and `None` is returned.